# Ionic 3 and GPS spoofing detection?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, gps, spoofing

Is there a way to reliably detect GPS spoofing in ionic (currently using version 3.20)? I have made a pretty extensive research and all I could find on some relatively old threads are cordova plugins which either do not support latest Android version or the latest version of ionic.

I have tried these but to no avail:

- cordova-plugin-fakelocations
- cordova-plugin-mock-location-checker
- cordova-plugin-mock-location

Ideally it would be great to have a solution that works for both ios and android.

Any help would be highly appreciated.